# Does d3.js provide smart devices event handling capability

Tags: d3.js

I have developed some charts in `d3.js`. I am moving towards mobile first. I want to know does `d3.js` provide support for Touch gestures/Touch Events like

Touch Events

- touchstart
- touchend
- touchmove
- touchcancel

Touch gestures

- Tap
- Double tap
- Press/Hold
- Slide
- Flick
- Drag
- Swipe
- Pan
- Rotate
- Pinch
- Spread/Stretch
- Press and tap
- Press and drag
- Rotate

Do I need to use `touch event handling libraries`?

Comment: The only d3 events I currently know of are http://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/9e6b87735d2da05813e3 otherwise it may be the case of finding other libraries. Take a look https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Touch

Comment: could you find any solution?